# How to pass route data from children of componentless route

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to access the `data` property of my routing configuration for an animation:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // ... other routes
  {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'calendar',
    data: { animation : 'I can access this' },  // I don't need this
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'month',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'day',
        data: { animation : 'But not this' },   // This is what I want
        loadChildren: () => import(...),
      },
      {
        path: 'month',
        data: { animation : 'Or this' },        // This is what I want
        loadChildren: () => import(...),
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Specifically, I'm trying to access it as per the Angular Doc's [Route transition animations guide](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations#router-outlet):

html

```
<div [@animate]="prepareAnimation(o)">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet" name="calendar"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

component

```
prepareAnimation(outlet: RouterOutlet): string {
  console.log(outlet.activatedRouteData.animation)
  return outlet.activatedRouteData.animation
}
```

This always `console.log()`s "`I can access this`", but I need to get the data values associated with the `day` & `month` routes.

**Is there any way to do this?**

P.S.  I do not want to flatten the routes because it changes the routing structure undesirably

Answer (score 0):

To access the `data` property of your routing configuration following code might help you:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.url.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data);
   });
}
```